# Paser symbol(pdb) file and get function name and offset

Tags: python, debugging, symbols, pdb, debug-symbols

I want to know what is the easiest way to parse a PDB (debugging symbol) file and get function name and offset in binary, preferably in Python.

Thanks,

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about Python but you should be able to do it using [DIA API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6tay6cz.aspx). See [Querying the .Pdb File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eee38t3h.aspx) for example.

Comment: The question is about Python, not C++.

Comment: @MattDMo: COM is programming language independent. You can do COM in any programming language, theoretically.